# How can I implement strcpy() and sorting of a struct in C?

Tags: c, sorting, struct, strcpy

I am making a small ANSI C application using GCC in Ubuntu which uses strcpy() and sorting.

My header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DECKSZ 52

typedef struct card {
    enum {ACE=1, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING} pips;
    enum {SPADES, CLUBS, HEARTS, DIAMONDS} suit;
    char cardName[20];
} card;

card deck[DECKSZ];

void initDeck(card[]);
void labelCards();
void shuffleDeck(card[]);
void swap(card*,card*);
```

My main file:

```
#include "CardOps.h"

void initDeck(card deck[]) {
    int counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < DECKSZ; counter++) {
        deck[counter].pips = (const)((counter % 13) + 1);
        deck[counter].suit = (const)(counter / 13);
    }
}

void labelCards() {
    char pips[13][6] = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
    char suits[4][9] = {"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    int i;
    card cardName;
    for (i = 0; i < DECKSZ; i++) {
        strcpy(cardName, pips[i]);
        strcpy(cardName, suits[i]);
    }
}

int displayCards(int numCards) {
    int i, countCards;
    if (numCards > 52)
        countCards = 52;
    else
        countCards = numCards;
    for (i = 0; i < countCards; i++) {
        printf(cardName);
    }
    return countCards;
}

void shuffleDeck(card deck[]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < DECKSZ; i++) {
        j = rand() % DECKSZ;
        swap(&deck[i], &deck[j]);
    }
}

void SortCards() {

}

void swap(card *c1, card *c2) {
    card temp;
    temp = *c1;
    *c1 = *c2;
    *c2 = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    initDeck(deck);
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am trying to implement the following functionality:

A function called LabelCards() that takes as an argument a void and
returns a void.  Use each of the two enumeration type members in the 
deck to assign a string to cardName, i.e. “Queen of Hearts”.  (You’ll 
want to create an array of strings “Ace”, “Two”, “Three”, etc. for the 
pips and a similar array for the suits to handle the string processing.) 
Note that you’ll need to use strcpy() to make the actual assignment 
to cardName.

A function called DisplayCards() that takes as an argument an 
integer N, and returns an integer. The function should display the 
cardName of first the N cards in the deck.  The function returns the 
number of cards displayed, which could be less than the actual deck 
size.  For example, 53 cards cannot be displayed in a deck of 52; I
need to check for this and return the actual number of cards 
displayed.

A function called SortDeck() that takes and returns a void.  My
function should use the swap() algorithm to organize the cards in 
the deck first by their pips, and then according to their suit value.

Would somebody please help me get the functionality working? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not one specific question that is likely to help future visitors.  (There are at least two issues here:  sorting and strcpy.)  Asking two specific questions about how to sort and how to use strcpy might be more appropriate.

Comment: Okay I'll split it into two questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the declaration of `deck` in the header.  You should make it an `extern`, and move the declaration into the main file.

Your `initDeck` function is indexing the array with `DECKSZ` which is constant and out of bounds.  You probably meant to use `counter` instead.

`labelCards` is trying to copy the entire array into a single card.  The types don't match, and the loop variable isn't used.

`displayCards` prints `cardName`, which doesn't exist.  Presumably you meant to print the `cardName` of a specific card.

Comment: `displayCards` is supposed to print the `cardName` of a specific card, yes.
How would I use the loop variable inside `labelCards`?

Comment: Where are the cards you want to label in `labelCards`?  Do you really need a separate function to label the cards, or can't you label each card as you initialize them in `initDeck`?  Also, for a local array of strings, you should use `static const char *pipNames[] = { "Ace", ... };`, and don't forget that the array is indexed from 0, but your ace has a value of 1.

Comment: In `displayCards`, where are the cards you want to display?  If you pass the deck as an argument, you can index it with `i`, and print the `cardName` of *that* card.

Comment: Also, `strcpy` will overwrite the target string, so the suit will overwrite the pips in the card.  You could use `strcpy` for the pips, and `strcat` for the suit, but that would leave you with `"AceSpades"` for instance.  Maybe `sprintf("%s of %s", pipNames[pips-1], suitNames[suit])` would be better (or `snprintf` so you don't overflow)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this is an assignment with some silly rules.  I guess you have to assume there is a single global deck, and you have to use strcpy.  Good luck with that!